# ASP.NET Web Forms Readonly DatePicker Not Posting Value Back

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I have a web forms page with a standard input on it:

```
<asp:TextBox id="documentDate2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control readonly" Readonly=True />
```

The control renders out an input element, which jQuery datepicker gets applied to the readonly element.  The readonly aspect is established from the server; the reason why it's still being established as a datepicker is the readonly attribute is dynamically applied (set from the server, through a process checking for certain permissions).  There is some JS on the page modifying the date and setting it on the client.

When a save occurs, the control is coming up blank, but the form posted a value to the server.  If I check in the immediate window

```
documentDate2.Text //Equals ""
```

But if I check:

```
Request.Form[documentDate2.UniqueID] //Equals "6/1/2018"
```

For some reason, the value isn't being loaded from the post data.  If it happened all the time, I would expect it to be an issue with readonly and the control postback process, but most of the time it does in fact work.  Also, other controls on the page (non-readonly) are posting back values, so it's not a general postback problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the [TextBox is implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4fe4349175f4c5091d972a7e56ea12012f1e7170/System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs). If `ReadOnly` is set to true. the value is stored and [loaded](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4fe4349175f4c5091d972a7e56ea12012f1e7170/System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs#L648) from ViewState. Post data is ignored.

I know it's not the perfect solution but you could use a Hidden input to set that date back to the server.